# Centre of orbifold fundamental group of torus (Klein bottle) with one cone point

Tags: gr.group-theory, gt.geometric-topology

$\newcommand{\orb}{\mathrm{orb}}$Let $T$ ($K$) be the torus (Klein bottle) with one cone point of order $q\geq 2$. The presentation of their orbifold fundamental groups are  easy to find. Namely,

$$\pi_1^{\orb}(T)=\{a,b\ |\ (aba^{-1}b^{-1})^q=1\}.$$

$$\pi_1^{\orb}(K)=\{a,b\ |\ (aba^{-1}b)^q=1\}.$$

Want to know the centre of these two groups. Are they trivial?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

These groups have trivial centers.  As one proof, they are both fuchsian and so embed in $\mathrm{PSL}(2, \mathbb{R})$ (well, the orientation preserving subgroups do).  However, elements of $\mathrm{PSL}$ that commute must have common fixed points on the "circle at infinity" of the hyperbolic plane.

Comment: Thanks a lot Sam! I was expecting it to be true. For more than one cone points case, I have a direct proof of the triviality of the centre, but this case was troubling.

Answer (score 7):

The groups have trivial center, as pointed out by Sam Nead. Another, more combinatorial, way to show this is to apply the algorithm from [1], which decides whether any given one-relator group has a non-trivial center or not. If one wishes to be very explicit, one can even compute an explicit generating set for a finite index surface group inside the groups, see [2], particularly §5, where the Reidemeister-Schreier method is used to find a one-relator presentation on $4q-2$ generators for such a finite index subgroup.

${}$

${}$

[1] *Baumslag, G.; Taylor, Tekla*, [**The centre of groups with one defining relator**](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02063216), Math. Ann. 175, 315-319 (1968). [ZBL0157.34901](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0157.34901).

[2] *Baumslag, Gilbert; Troeger, Douglas*, Virtually free-by-cyclic one-relator groups. I., Fine, Benjamin (ed.) et al., Aspects of infinite groups. A Festschrift in honor of Anthony Gaglione. Papers of the conference, Fairfield, USA, March 2007 in honour of Anthony Gaglione’s 60th birthday. Hackensack, NJ: World Scientific (ISBN 978-981-279-340-9/hbk). Algebra and Discrete Mathematics (Hackensack) 1, 9-25 (2008). [ZBL1188.20023](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1188.20023).

Comment: Thanks Carl for the detailed reply. I will look at the references.

Comment: This is a sledgehammer to crack a nut! Plus note that Sam Nead's argument works verbatim for all hyperbolic orbifolds.

Comment: @HJRW Agreed on the sledgehammer (for the first part!), but it is such a nice paper that it is worth reading anyway :-) For the second part, it is nice to see more explicit generating sets, I think.

Comment: It’s worth reading if you like one-relator groups, but it’s the wrong way to study 2-dimensional orbifolds! These comments are really addressed at the OP: This answer is nice, but you should accept @SamNead’s (and possibly ask him to add more details), especially if you want to understand all 2-orbifolds. Gromov pointed out >35 years ago that we should be studying these kinds of examples with geometry (and Dehn would have agreed with him).

Comment: @HJRW I agree that SamNead's answer should be the accepted one, as OP is clearly more interested in the geometric side! (Magnus might have disagreed with him, though -- "da sind Sie also blind gegangen", after all!)

Comment: @Carl-FredrikNybergBrodda: Indeed! My point is that the judgement of both Gromov and posterity is that Dehn was right. I persist with this point because it's still a serious issue for the field: I regularly see people working on the combinatorial side exaggerating the difficulty of results that are trivial from a geometric point of view.

Comment: @HJRW Agreed! (For the most part, with the remainder coming down to my ignorance; I confess I may at times be one of those people you speak of, as much as I try to avoid it...).

Answer (score 2):

> The centre of any non-cyclic one-relator group with torsion
> is trivial.

Moreover,

> the centraliser of any non-identity element of a one-relator group with torsion
> is cyclic.

This is [B. B. Newman’s theorem (1973)](https://doi.org/10.1017/S1446788700015044).

Comment: Thanks Anton for the precise reference. I find this more general fact interesting.